# How to get sender profile picture of mail using mailcore2

Tags: ios, swift, mailcore2

I am doing mail application in swift with using mailcore2. In this application I need to fetch all mail with detail. and doing following code for that.

```
let imapSession = MCOIMAPSession()
imapSession.hostname = "imap.gmail.com"
imapSession.connectionType = .TLS
imapSession.port = 993
imapSession.username = "abc@gmail.com"
imapSession.password = "12345"

let requestKind = (MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.headers.rawValue | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.structure.rawValue | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.internalDate.rawValue | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.headerSubject.rawValue | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.flags.rawValue)

let fetchRange = MCOIndexSet.init(range: MCORangeMake(1, UInt64.max))

let imapMessagesFetchOp = imapSession.fetchMessagesByNumberOperation(withFolder: "INBOX", requestKind: MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind(rawValue: requestKind), numbers: fetchRange)
            self.imapMessagesFetchOp?.start({ (error, messages, vanishedMessages) in})
```

I got the messages with detail using this method, but I can't get profile picture of sender user of mail.

Answer (score 0):

Emails don't have "profile pictures". You will need to use a detail specific to sender to lookup a profile in some other manner.

For example, if you have a contact in the Address Book you could look it up by email address and use the picture from the contact.